# Which one is good Traffic shapping / Traffic Monitoring?

Tags: 11.10

I am new in ubuntu guys, which software should i use as traffic shapping in ubuntu? i use cfosspeed in windows to monitoring my bandwidth.

i've try search in the askbuntu.com but it answered, but too old aplication there, it's no uupdate since 2002 and it stopped in alpha version.

Answer (score 1):

I think L7-filter would do it (But I have not used it) http://l7-filter.sourceforge.net/